# What possible consequences can including the course on violations in organizations in university programs have?

Tags: ethics, conflict, education

University gives knowledge on a variety of professional skills. One important skill is missing in the list, it is the skill to detect wrong behavior in the organization. The topic is not easy, it is broad, hardly the young professional can explore the topic on his own. The benefits of including the topic in a course are evident, what are the consequences?

Comment: I suspect you mean "office politics"? I doubt you are "helpless".

Comment: College is not a job training center.  It's purpose is to teach a particular set of subjects.  You may or may not use them afterwards in your job.  If you want training, go to a vocational school.  Honestly your entire question just sounds like you have a rotten boss and need to quit-  most people get through their day to day job without giving a care about workplace politics.

Comment: I always complained that none of the university "management" courses taught the most common management technique of "fire fighting", which many managers use... aka running around like a headless chicken...

Comment: Hi Valery, and welcome to workplace SE. Office politics can certainly be infuriating. I think there might be an interesting question here, but in its current form it is not very concrete, and would tend to get opinion based answers that generate more heat than light. A more concrete question might be "How can I navigate the politics of a big organization as a new graduate?", and look at similar questions about large orgs on the site.

Comment: I swear I remember seeing some undergrads running around like headless chickens when I was at uni ... perhaps they were just blessed with management skills at a tender age ...

Comment: @AdamBurke that was at assignment hand-in time :)

Comment: I think it is not logical that the university teaches complex things, and gives no defense from office politics. The goal of the university is to teach to have a job. After that we know a lot, but do not know how to work. There are many hardships. In some organisations there are a lot of violations.

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Also, as written, this question is effectively a rant in disguise. You aren't really asking the question posed in the title, but rather ranting about why universities haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: I understand that the question as it is doesn't fit the context of the site. The question is provocative in its form. I believe that reformulating of the question will leave the question on the site. The topic is very important.

Answer (score 3):

I actually fundamentally agree that universities should include some form of education about potential workplace environments.

But I disagree that a lot of energy should be spent trying to educate students on how to play office politics. Universities have a sociological obligation not to encourage or perpetuate negative characteristics of workplace environments.

In addition, the course itself does not look good on an academic transcript. If I were a potential employer I'd rather a candidate study some academic subject rather than how to stab other coworkers in the back, or some other manifestation of the black arts that are office politics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree that the course should not teach office politics. It should be focused on 'defensive' strategies, not 'attacks'. Everybody must know if the environment is dangerous and from what side. Also it is good to know how to defend yourself, how to regulate the situation legally. Or be honest and understand that the situation won't change. Young people sometimes do not that. Especially it true for those who have studied a lot and focused on professional skills, often they do nothing about the environment and what dangers wait for them.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to disagree that there could be some significant value that could be found in a generalized office politics course at universities.

Every organization and its people are very different from each other, their goals are different, their interactions are different, their cultural settings are different. Therefore a single course cannot possibly cover all the possible variations in a pool of infinite combinations. An instructor could only provide some generalized rules of thumb and, almost certainly, most of them will break after entering a real workplace.

I would also like to argue that office politics is mostly learned by experience. And you don't have to enter an actual workplace to start gaining it. You start gaining it while participating in group student activities, which require some collective effort to achieve some collective goal (i.e. organization of a student conference). You can even do that before going to university.

In the case of op, it is also worth noting that there is no use in writing off the skills that one has already acquired. They are most certainly useful to be practically applied in a workplace and enable you to do your job. It is a simple matter of coming into reality that there is still much more to learn.

Also, check out Adam Burkes point that many courses do teach indirectly about intrigues in society.

Comment: The generalized course of office politics can give some basics, as many of university courses do. It can give some definitions. Having this basis, a student can easily search for his/her personal situation. The main goal of the course is to detect violations in organisations. Because what is in reality differs much from 'what should be'.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me universities do have a number of courses on intrigues in organizations. In fact they have entire departments, such as Anthropology (varieties of human society), Sociology (structures of human interaction), History (Machiavelli, the Ottoman Court ...), and Political Science.

I don't mean this dismissively. For example, I learnt a lot about working at a multinational corporation from David Fromkin's history of diplomacy in the First World War, *A Peace To End All Peace*.

I don't think I agree that the problems are straightforward, though. Internal politics certainly gets too complicated for me, sometimes.

Comment: These courses are not taught for everybody. Young people are more focused on professional skills, they think that skills are a success. It is not always true, often success in politics. Many people do not know where is the 'exit'. The situations in organisations are common, they follow some patterns, they can be understood.

Comment: In my country, and many others, no course is taught for everybody. Certain subjects may be required for certain majors or degrees. But I didn't see bouncers at the door to the lecture theatres where history was being taught.